# How can I unpack multidimensional c-style array type and declare std::array instance?

Tags: c++, templates, std, metaprogramming

I'm writing a template that can convert a c style multidimensional array to a std array and declare it.

1. get c-style array matrix

```
template <typename, typename IS = std::index_sequence<>>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl
{
    using type = IS;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t ... I>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl<T*, std::index_sequence<I...>>
    : public unpacked_array_type_impl<T, std::index_sequence<0u, I...>>
{ };

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... I>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl<T[N], std::index_sequence<I...>>
    : public unpacked_array_type_impl<T, std::index_sequence<I..., N>>
{ };

template<typename T>
struct unpacked_array_type
{
    using type = typename unpacked_array_type_impl<T>::type;
};
```

2. std array declaration

```
template<typename T, size_t size, size_t... more>
struct myArray_impl
{
    using type = std::array<typename myArray_impl<T, more...>::type, size>;
};

template<typename T, size_t size>
struct myArray_impl<T, size>
{
    using type = std::array<T, size>;
};

template<typename T, size_t size, size_t... more>
using myArray = typename myArray_impl<T, size, more...>::type;
```

Below is the code I want to achieve.

```
using example_type = int[4][10];
using real_type = std::remove_all_extents<example_type>::type
myArray<real_type, unpacked_array_type<example_type>::type> this_would_be_std_arr;
```

But I got C2993 error.

The problem is that std::integer_sequence cannot expand to the variable argument of myArray template.

I would appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First template return `std::index_sequence`, whereas the second take a list of number.

You might use `std::index_sequence` for both:

```
template<typename T, typename Seq>
struct myArray_impl;


template<typename T, size_t size, size_t... more>
struct myArray_impl<T, std::index_sequence<size, more...>>
{
    using type = std::array<typename myArray_impl<T, std::index_sequence<more...>>::type, size>;
};

template<typename T, size_t size>
struct myArray_impl<T, std::index_sequence<size>>
{
    using type = std::array<T, size>;
};

template<typename T, typename Seq>
using myArray = typename myArray_impl<T, Seq>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fq958v).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to build a stack of array extents with `std::index_sequence` and apply them to a template parameter pack, why not just define your specialization of `myArray_impl` to recursively deduce each extent from `typename T`?

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct myArray_impl
{
    using type = typename std::remove_cv<T>::type;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct myArray_impl<T[N]>
{
    using type = std::array<typename myArray_impl<T>::type, N>;
};

template <typename T>
using myArray = typename myArray_impl<T>::type;
```

Then you get the following example type aliases:

```cpp
myArray<const int[4]> // std::array<int, 4>>
myArray<float[4][10]> // std::array<std::array<float, 10>, 4>>
```

Comment: The code from the question is partial and will be used for more complex template code. Thank you for your efforts.